# issue with browser NSD digital rights management

Tags: google-chrome, browser, copy-paste, ctrl

After using browser for a few minutes I am not able to copy any thing nor am I able to right click on any web page also when I try to click on three dots on the top left corner it doesnot click there when I switch tabs it shows "NO PICTURE TAKING" for browser.

this is what its showing when I switch to other applications using alt+tab (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMrXW.png)

I tried clearing cache and also re-installing chrome browser but the issue is still there.

Comment: Hi, were you to find any resolution for this. I am also facing this since last 2-3 weeks.

Comment: Hi Did you find any solution? Facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Updating the chrome version works for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If its happening in chrome, then follow the below steps :
Go to settings -> privacy & security ->site settings -> protected content id's -> In default behaviour (select Don't allow sites to play protected content)